# Return 'last modified' time

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

How can I get `last update` of spreadsheet using Google Sheets API v4?

I tried to use this https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get but it doesn't give me any information about last modified time.

Answer (score -1):

I found i can use this Google Drive API endpoint https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get?apix_params=%7B%22fileId%22%3A%2216xjvFOEmVwEwJEJ07jo8UVfGcqMonngHT-TK43pBVRc%22%7D for this.